# extract value from variable stata

Tags: stata

I have variables:

```
set obs 1000
g X= rnormal(0,1)
egen t=fill(1 2)
```

I need to generate a new variable, that would consist of one value: the first value of X. I tried:

```
 separate X, by(_n <= 1)
```

and

```
gen X1 = X if t<=1
```

But these options give me a vector 100x1 with the first value - the value I need and 99 of empty cells. How can I generate simply a one value variable:1x1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write two lines of codes my friend

```
gen X1 = X if t<=1
replace X1=X1[_n-1] if missing(X1[_n])
```

and

```
local my_parameter=X1[1]
```

and then you happily use your `my_parameter' macro in your **arma** regressions

```
. di `my_parameter'
-.44087866
```

remember, to use a macro (more usually called a parameter in other languages) in a regression in stata you need to embed its name with `'

Comment: but this creates a 100x1 vector of repeated first value. I need just one value

Comment: you need to specify what you wanna do with that variable. You can store it into a vector using mata if you need to, or perhaps in a macro

Comment: i need it to run ARMA model: arima RV in 1/X1, ar(1/2) ma(1/2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with the other two helpful answers already posted, but when I read *"How can I generate simply a one value variable:1x1?"*, I cant help but think you are looking for a scalar or a macro.

If that is true they you might be better off with

```
sum X in 1
di r(mean)
```

From here, storing this value to use later is trivial:

```
sca MyVar = r(mean)
```

From `help summarize`, you will see that `sum` stores the mean, min and max among many other useful measures.

To see yourself, run `return list` after the call to `sum` to see what is returned.

By using `in 1` you are restricting the `summarize` command to only run for the first observation. Naturally then, many of the scalars returned by `summarize` will equal the value you desire.

If you wish, you may also precede `sum` with `quietly` to suppress the output, or add the `meanonly` option to calculate only the mean along with suppressing the display.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will point you in a helpful direction

```
generate X1 = X[1]
```

The point is that X[1] is the value of X in the first observation. Now having said that, what do you want to do with that value? Your dataset has 1000 observations. Do you want a local or global macro? A scalar? If you intend to use it in a formula applied to all 1000 observations, then perhaps a variable with the same value for every observation will be sufficient.